# The character encoding of the html document was not declared in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

i got above error in .aspx page. I add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

to my aspx page but still i got this error plz help me...thanks

Comment: is your page using a layout file?

Comment: no page not using layout file

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting a CodePage in your Page directive (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

For example, for ISO-8859-1, codepage is 28591 :

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="yourpage.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="yourpage" 
codePage="28591" %>
```

and for utf-8, codepage is 65001 :

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="yourpage.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="yourpage" 
codePage="65001" %>
```

For a list of codepages, see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

hope this will help